# How to make Row as Column in my case in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have 2 tables

**ProductPast**

```
productID   deptID    year   month    price
-------------------------------------------
1           10        2015   1        45
1           10        2015   2        65


2           11        2015   1        45
2           11        2015   2        65
2           11        2015   3        44
```

**ProductCurrent**

```
productID   deptID    year   month    price
-------------------------------------------
1           10        2016   1        12
1           10        2016   2        46
1           10        2016   3        77

2           11        2016   1        88
```

**Expected output**

```
productID   deptID    Month    PrevYear   PrevPrice    CurrYear    CurrPrice
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           10          1       2015        45          2016            12
1           10          2       2015        65          2016            46
1           10          3       2015        0           2016            77

2           11          1       2015        45           2016            88
2           11          1       2015        65           2016            0
2           11          1       2015        44           2016            0
```

I tried to make unionall and group like below in my stored procedure

```
SELECT ProductID,DeptID,month
into #rec
FROM (
    SELECT ProductID,DeptID,year,month FROM ProductPast
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ProductID,DeptID,year,month FROM ProductCurrent
    )
group by ProductID,DeptID,month


SELECT ProductID,DeptID,month,p.year as PrevYear, c.year as CurrYear, p.price as prevprice,c.price as currprice
FROM rec
LEFT JOIN ProductPast p on p.productid = rec.productID and p.month = rec.month
LEFT JOIN ProductCurrent c on c.productid = rec.productID and c.month = rec.month
```

but I didn't get the exact result.

Comment: Your query seems fairly correct, what was the result you got?

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis when i see `sum(prevPrice),sum(currPrice)` from the final result, it was wrong. it's give more than what it has

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, a full outer join would seem to be what you need here:

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(pp.productID, pc.productID) AS productID,
    COALESCE(pp.deptID, pc.deptID) AS deptID,
    COALESCE(pp.month, pc.month) AS Month,
    COALESCE(pp.year, 2015) AS PrevYear,
    COALESCE(pp.price, 0) AS PrevPrice,
    COALESCE(pc.year, 2016) AS CurrYear,        
    COALESCE(pc.price, 0) AS CurrPrice
FROM ProductPast pp
FULL OUTER JOIN ProductCurrent pc
    ON pp.productID = pc.productID AND
       pp.deptID = pc.deptID AND
       pp.year = pc.year - 1 AND
       pp.month = pc.month
ORDER BY
    COALESCE(pp.productID, pc.productID),
    COALESCE(pp.deptID, pc.deptID),
    COALESCE(pp.month, pc.month);
```

[image]

### Demo

Note that another way to do this would be to use a calendar table containing all years and months (and maybe also products and departments).  Then, you could just do a series of regular inner/left joins to get the result you want.